# Does $90 / hr convert to 145k salary?

Tags: salary, contractors, contracting

I received an offer for $90 / hour as a full time 1099 contractor for 40 hours a week with zero benefits based in the US (Bay Area) that would convert to full time w2 salary with health / vacation benefits at $145k a year. Is this contract rate to salary conversion low?

For being a contractor with 25 unpaid holidays / vacation it calculates to around 165k a year.  Are the other benefits worth 20k?  Maybe insurance is up to 10k?  Then they'll pay for a laptop and other items?

I really like the rate and salary.  It's a big raise for me.  I just want to know if I'm being out-negotiated for the conversion of contract to salary.  I like the contract rate as I receive health insurance through my wife.

Comment: You need to give more details. Are you now exempt? How many hours a week? Where is this? These things are not always clear-cut. Sometimes, you need to negotiate, especially now that some of your taxes are being paid by your employer.

Comment: Does the contractor position also include health insurance, or do you have to buy your own? That's a significant cost that gets covered when you convert to full-time.

Comment: Yes, health benefits can easily be worth $20k, depending on the plan.

Comment: Is this gross? I make that around $188k Pa assuming an 8 hour day and 261 working days in  year ( and this  the UK definition of working days)

Comment: Yes, the 188k Pa estimate would be gross before all the applicable taxes without any holidays / vacation.  I'm just wondering if this gross estimate can be compared somehow with a full time W2 salaried at 145k somehow.  Cause if I understand correctly, a W2 salary figure like 145k is gross as well before taxes.

Comment: Because they said they'll want all contractors to go full time salary.  In that case if I go salary they'll take money out of my pay for health insurance I won't use.  So I would effectively lose money.

Comment: Thanks for asking, they said the company didn't have the accounting personnel to make out of state people employees and it was easier to make them contractors.  Now they're hiring the people to convert the out of state 1099 contractors as W2 employees within the next six months.  So I asked them what the salary would be when I converted an they said 145k.  I'm wondering if this conversion from $90 an hour is equivalent to 145k salary in Bay Area.

Comment: Do you already have a place to live in the area or are you moving into the area? Expect to pay around 35k/year to rent a small apartment.

Comment: Thanks for asking.  The role itself is remote but I thought I would mention where the employer is for applicable taxes.  I'm trying to figure how what goes into calculating the 145k figure for the employer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, kudos for the offer :)

This should help you calculate employer cost for W2 employee

https://medium.com/@ai/how-much-does-an-employer-pay-for-a-w2-full-time-employee-961c6fb7aab0

from this article 145k + 17.31% comes up to 170K

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the number of hours you work per week. Assuming that you take two weeks off a year, then the number of hours you are working is just 32.25 hours per week while earning that.

Comment: Okay thanks, while taking 30 paid days a year it's still something like 160k a year.  I figure health insurance for the company could be up to 10k maybe?  I'm just trying to understand if I'm being out-negotiated.

Comment: If this includes things like paid holidays and the health insurance figure, it is hard for us to tell

Comment: Thank you, yes the full time salary would include health insurance and paid holidays / vacation

Comment: @Todd who cares what the company would pay for health insurance.  You will need to pay for it.  Maybe the company is better at negotiating rates than you are.

Comment: Yeah, for health insurance, I'm trying to understand how much it is for them.  I receive health insurance through my wife so when joining salary, they're budgeting health insurance for me but I wouldn't use it potentially.  So I'd lose that money yeah?